# How to list installed plugins on a Minecraft Server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

How do I get a list of installed plugins on my server from the client?

It's minecraft_server.1.8.4.jar running on a Linux server.

Comment: /plugins yields "Unknown command. Try /help for a list of commands"

Comment: First, install essentials. Second, run /plugins. I think.

Comment: You should specify if it is your server and which type of server it is. There is plenty of types of servers....And - does it have any plugin at all? (I mean that you seen some in work, it also can by vanila server without plugins)

Comment: @Elias Benevedes - No dice.

Comment: @NitroxDM maybe [craftbukkit](http://wiki.bukkit.org/CraftBukkit_Commands) server core instead? Looks like the plugin command is explicitly listed on that page.

Comment: @NitroxDM what type of server is it? Vanilla, bukkit, spigot... What is the type of your server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Vanilla

When using the Vanilla Minecraft server, you cannot install plugins and therefore there will not be any on your server.

### Bukkit / Spigot

On Bukkit / Spigot servers, you can use the `/plugins` command as others said in the comments. It also shows which plugins have been enabled successfully (green) and which failed (red).

Additionally, you can look at the `plugins` directory in the server folder. Each `.jar`-file should represent one plugin. You need file-access to the server though, and I recommend you to use the command.